# Search without iterator for Map

Tags: java

Is it possible to search without iterator without using map.

```
    Map<String,Short> map = new HashMap<String,Short>();
    map.put("String2", (short)2);
    map.put("String1", (short)1);
    map.put("String3", (short)4);
```

I am looking for a way to get the value based on the key (Return 2 for value String2). Is Map the right one to use in this scenario.

Thanks !

Comment: Does `map.get("String2")` not do what you want?  That will return `2` with your map.

Comment: I think that will just convert it into a list.

Comment: `map.keySet()`, as the name implies, returns a `Set`, not a `List`.

Comment: Have you seen the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) documentation?

Comment: `map.keyset()` gives you a `Set<String>` containing all of the keys.

Comment: Is anybody know how to do this in Java 8 by using lambdas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning values based on a key is precisely what maps are for.

To retrieve your value you can simply do:

```
short returnVal = map.get("String2");
```